How in highmaps (highcharts) for Vue2 to connect module "modules/tiledwebmap.js" for "OpenStreetMap"?
How in highmaps (highcharts) for Vue to import and connect module "https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/tiledwebmap.js" for "OpenStreetMap"?
it would also be great if you would send an example demo.

The setup is almost identical as it with Vanilla JS setup, with only difference that you need to import and intialize TiledWebMap module within your application.
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import MapsModule from "highcharts/modules/map";
import TiledWebMap from "highcharts/modules/tiledwebmap";
import HighchartsVue from "highcharts-vue";

MapsModule(Highcharts);
TiledWebMap(Highcharts);

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nostalgic-https-j59mgn?file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.js%3A4%2C1-13%2C25
References:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/tiledwebmap
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue?tab=readme-ov-file#importing-highcharts-modules
